# decrypting/decoding AES256 using JavaScript BigQuery UDF

Tags: javascript, encryption, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I have a crypted column on a BigQuery table that I need too decrypt.
The encryption mechanic used to encrypt the column is AES 256.
This is the code that was used for the encryption process.

However, this didn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong or whether or not I am using the library wrong or if my logic for decrypting is JavaScriptis flawed !
I am hoping to get some guidance on how to do this properly and make it work.

Comment: So again, just to be clear. The key is plain text, not a Base64. Then what is vector? Can you give couple of more example pairs for both cleartext,encrypted,key used.

Comment: It's the initialization vector (iv) used in the encryption process

Comment: As for more examples, you can use the encryption method to get some as the data I have is sensitive !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you:

```
WITH EncryptedInput AS (
  SELECT FROM_BASE64('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') as ciphertext,
    FROM_HEX('2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05') AS key
)
SELECT AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES(b'', 'AES_CBC_PKCS', key), ciphertext, '') AS plaintext
FROM EncryptedInput;
```

returns:

```
{   accessKey: "ASIAJ32FWBMGSR7NDWHQ",  secretKey: "4U0zxuLaqs0DzGNiyI8nyoSKhA1MhptEELEvu+lY",  securityToken: "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",  expirationDate: "1361277588000"}
```